# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:661) python2.7

Tags: python, bash, sockets, ssl, protocols

I have tried every kind of number and option given to me, even went into the protocol section of bash and looked all over various sites, no matter what do with my code i can't get away from that error(as said in title), this is my code and full error message, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, i'd really appreciate that.
Versions i've tried:

```
SSLv2,SSLv3,SSLv23[1],TLSv1,TLSv1_1,TLSv1_2 with all proper apache 
configurations, and encryption when making the SSL self-signed cert
```

version of server:

```
cert is version 3
cert signature algorithm is PKCS #1 SHA-256 With RSA Encryption
```

Version of kali linux i'm running:

```
4.14.0-kali1-amd64
```

Error message:

```
anon@kali:~/Desktop/python scripts$ python SSL\ client.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "SSL client.py", line 21, in <module>
ssl_socket = context.wrap_socket(c, server_side=False, 
do_handshake_on_connect=True, suppress_ragged_eofs=True, 
server_hostname='vulnerable')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 363, in wrap_socket
_context=self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 611, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 840, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number 
(_ssl.c:661)
```

My code:

```
import socket
import requests
import ssl

t_host = "vulnerable"
t_port = 443


c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect((t_host,t_port))
c.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: vulnerable\r\n\r\n")
getRequest = "GET /HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: vulnerable\r\n\r\n"
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
r = requests.get('https://vulnerable/',verify=False)

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_verify_locations(cafile="/etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt")

ssl_socket = context.wrap_socket(c, server_side=False, do_handshake_on_connect=True, suppress_ragged_eofs=True, server_hostname='vulnerable')
ssl_socket.connect(('vulnerable', 443 ))
re = c.recv(4096)
ssl_socket.send(getRequest)
print ssl_socket.recv(1024)
print ssl_socket.recv(1024)
print (re.decode('UTF-8'))
print r.text
```

Result i am looking for when ran successfully:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2016 01:02:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Nov 2016 11:13:07 GMT
ETag: "70-5426eac41e995"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 112
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: *"I have tried every kind of number and option given to me..."* - this statement provides no information of what you've actually tried and thus is useless to narrow down the problem. There are many hits when you search for [python "ssl wrong version number"](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+"ssl+wrong+version+number"). Please check these information and if this does not help show at least what you've tried and where you've failed. Also provide the SSL versions actually supported by the server you test - because one cause for this problem is if the server does not support current TLS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ah yes i will do that, thank you for the comment :)